# InAppBrowser opens a blank page on iOs 10

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, cordova, inappbrowser

I've been 3 days trying to solve why my cordova application is opening a "blank" page when function cordova.InAppBrowser.open is fired and I'm not being able to solve it at all, could you help me with it?

This is where I call that function on app.js:

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open("https://google.es", "_blank", "location=no,toolbar=no,transitionstyle=crossdissolve");
```

May it be a security problem or something like that? I've tried adding that on the index html meta: but didn't work.

```
        <meta http-equiv=“Content-Security-Policy” content=“default-src 'self’ gap: mailto:; connect-src https://google.es; style-src 'self’ 'unsafe-inline’; script-src 'self’ 'unsafe-eval’ 'unsafe-inline’; img-src * data:; media-src *”>
```

I'm working with Xcode 7.3 and there's no error shown on the console by the way.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to add the following in `config.xml`:

```
<allow-intent href="https://google.es/*" />
```

or a wildcard to allow all intents (which is not recommended):

```
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

Make sure you have the cordova whitelist plugin installed: [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist).

Comment: Thanks David, but it didn't solve my problem. I tried both options and my app keeps showing a blank page.

Comment: Could you please also try this one: `<allow-navigation href="*" />`. And do not remove the entries from your Content-Security-Policy.

Comment: Not working neither. I don't know what could be happening really, I'm feeling really frustrated right now. Maybe I've some configuration missing? Is there anything I could do to "test" or to realize what's the error?

Thanks for your answers anyway!

Comment: You can run your project using XCode and check the native-log if the InAppBrowser-plugin logs something useful.

Comment: The only error I can see is this one:

NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100

Answer (score 0):

> I'm working with Xcode 7.3

It *might* not be the cause of this issue, but you should update to Xcode 8 to work with iOS 10 - Xcode 8 contains the iOS 10 SDK.

But actually there's no reason not to update to Xcode 9 which contains the iOS 11 SDK: download it [here](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_9_GM_seed_build_9A235/Xcode_9_GM_seed.xip)

Comment: Okay, so I updated to Xcode 9 and now the console log shows me more information.

Now I can see this error:

NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1100

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after trying to whitelist the url with no success I finnally ""fixed"" the problem. At least for now, while I try to find something better.

I put this code at the end of AppDelegate.m, so now I don't validate that url's have a valid certificate.

```
@implementation NSURLRequest(DataController)
+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host
{
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Thank you for your answers!